# How to use QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I need to use QAbstractItemModel with QTreeView in PyQt.

In the dropMimeData method I want to remove the source row (if it is a certain MIME_TYPE.) How do I get the row and parentIndex of the source? Or do I need to do that from some other method.

`def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, row, column, parentIndex):`

Comment: Have you determined that a QTreeWidget will not suffice? What about a QTreeView + QStandardItemModel? What are you needs that require you to subclass and create your own custom model?

Comment: @Tim: I think your edit, while yes it makes a point about the clarity of the question, does significantly change what the OP might be asking. It might have been better for you to make a comment and let the OP adjust that cruft. I was more interested in hearing why he needs an abstract model as opposed to his question about dropMimeData which I believe might actually be irrelevant.

Comment: @jdi I haven't determined anything. I started with the closest thing I could find that seemed close to what I needed. I need one tree of source items (single column of names for now) and another tree that I want to drop those itmes on. On the target tree I need to move the items to a different location. I'm assuming that would be an internal drag and drop then remove the source item. I used subclassed models only to have a way to tell which tree the items were coming from so I wouldn't delete any from the source tree.

Comment: @jdi I couldn't find a DragDropMode that would act like internalMove and also allow drops from another view. There should be a simpler way to do this, and I would be grateful to learn it. Someone else suggested using the subclasses.

Comment: QAbstractItemModel is meant for when you need a custom type of model, but just for doing your drag and drop its not necc. You would have to implement more than you should need to. QStandardItemModel should be fully functional and ready to use with a QTreeView. You would just subclass one of those and then reimplement the drag*Event/drop*Event methods. If you want to keep two completely separate models then ditch this whole mess and just subclass QTreeWidget which has a built-in model.

Answer (score 3):

*My comments were running too long so I figured I would start an answer now with the info.*

QAbstractItemModel is a base class which is there for when you need a customized way of modeling your data that does not fit one of the existing ones, such as where to source the data and how to represent them as items. It is not ready to use out of the box, as it needs to have a number of methods implemented. You should probably not be starting with this class unless you have a compelling reason to do so, as it requires much more work to get up and running.

For simply needing to do drag and drop, and using basic items, a QStandardItemModel should be ready to go for your use. You just create QStandardItems and populate the model. For drag and drop, you would subclass the model and just implement the appropriate drag*Event and drop*Event methods to suit your needs.

Using a QStandardItemModel + QTreeView allows you to have multiple views all using the same model and visualizing it different at the same time. But given that you said you want to keep two different sets of independent data, and that you are new to Qt, I would highly recommend you just use two QTreeWidgets. A QTreeWidget is an all-inclusive package of the view and the model. This will be much easier for you to use for now.

Using the QTreeWidget, you would subclass them and implement the necessary drag and drop events just as you would for QTreeView, but you no longer have to worry about the models separately.

Here is a link to a post regarding drag and drop with QTreeWidget: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/5910-QTreeWidget-Drag-and-drop
They mention the recommended methods to implement, and also what you should do with a subclass of QTreeWidgetItem to define the mimeData.

Comment: "You can always reimplement QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*) and create your own QDrag object specifying the drag type (move or copy) by hand." 
This looks like one of the things I was needing to know. My original question was where do I look to get a basic understanding of these classes and how to use them. For PyQt, it looks like the only place is the class references and online examples (mostly in C++) and posting lots of questions.  Seems I never had trouble finding good books and tutorials for Java. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @hosscomp: The docs for the C++ API are pretty much the same for python aside from the syntax. Good book: http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html. Its just a matter of reading the C++ documentation which is pretty abundant. They have an entire section on Drag and Drop

Comment: Thanks. I think that book will be very helpful to me. I just today discovered how to add the dragEnterEvent handler to the TreeView and check to see if event.source() is self.

Comment: I have been reading the book and added dragMoveEvent handler to my QTreeView subclass that sets drop action to Qt.MoveAction if source is self. It still did a move instead of a copy and still went through dropMineData. But then I ran it in Spider (instead of Eclipse) and it works the way I wanted it to. It also worked from IDLE and the command line. I can't figure out the difference.

Comment: @hosscomp: It had different behavior simply being launched under a different IDE? I would only guess that it might have to do with referencing different interpreters or different Qt versions? I usually just launch mine from a command line. Thats the sure test to know if its really working right.

Comment: That is good to know because I like using Eclipse. I can't find a different reference though.